# elements disappearing until i hover over them (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using flatstrap (a flattened version of twitter bootstrap). I have a simple stacked nav tabs with each tabs url set to #option1 etc. I then have the IDs set to the same options as the tabs.

So when i click on a tab it takes me to that location on the page. Now this is actually working but on chrome my fixed nav bar at the top and the tabs down the left hand side disappear until i hover over them. Everything is fine in IE and Firefox.

I've been looking at this for the past couple of hours and can't seem to find the issue, is it a bug or am i missing something obvious?

The page is at http://www.385studios.co.uk/asset/page.html

Comment: I think this might be a bug in Chrome's renderer. I've had similar issues on the backbonejs.org site sometimes

Comment: if thats the case, any idea where we report the issues to Google?

Comment: Found it, it's under tools in chrome. I doubt they'll do anything about though.

Answer (score 0):

You got a javascript error on your page. Can't check it but maybe that's the problem. On the end of your html document there is the following code:

```
function allCheckboxesToggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(&#39;customCheckbox&#39;);
  for(var i in checkboxes)
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

It should be:

```
function allCheckboxesToggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('customCheckbox');
  for(var i in checkboxes)
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

Comment: ah yes, i was aware of that error. I copied this page page from another and forgot to delete that. I use notepad++ with an addon to sort all the indentation - it seems to change the single quote marks. I've deleted the javascript but i still get the same error. thanks